# How to hide/show an option on click?

Tags: jquery, select, show-hide

The select is sometimes too big so I want to **filter** it. I will have 3 checkboxes to **turn off/on** some options based on values. Like in the sample on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/radek/ggWJu/)

- if the value of an option contains `d` hide it - in my example we need to hide 2 options
- if the checkbox is unchecked show the value

Could be done in jQuery. Any idea how?

It is good enough for me if it works in firefox ( chrome is good too but not necessary, the same for safari )

## NOTE:

There are going to be **3 checkboxes** to filter values that contain `w`, `d` and ,`h`. So the hiding/showing must work for all of them.

---

Final code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/radek/ggWJu/20/) based on @ShankarSangoli answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hiding an `option` in a select list is not supported in all the browsers. `jQuery` even cannot do anything to make it cross browser supported. But we can disable the option using `disabled` property.

Here is the working demo with option disabled on checkbox click.

http://jsfiddle.net/ggWJu/8/

Here is the working demo to add/remove option from the select box on checkbox click. It adds the option at the same location where it was removed from.

http://jsfiddle.net/ggWJu/9/

Here is the fiddle which will add/remove all the options if the option value contains the checkbox value.

http://jsfiddle.net/ggWJu/10/

Comment: I need to remove/hide the options. Making them `disabled` won't help me.

Comment: It doesn't work for all values that contain `d`. Only for 3d. It seems to me that it is so because the `3d` is in the checkbox value.

Comment: Yes, its because I have set the value of checkbox as "3d". It will look for whatever value you set in the checkbox.

Comment: It needs to be generic. Let's say if the checkbox's value is `d` I need to hide/show all options that contain this letter.

Comment: Could you have a look why it doesn't work? It won't return all options back. http://jsfiddle.net/radek/ggWJu/13/

Comment: Ticking 'd' mess up with 'w' :-) Tick 'd' and then untick 'd'. After that there is only one value of 'w' but so many times.

Comment: Check the correct url http://jsfiddle.net/ggWJu/15/ it is working fine  I again tested it.

Comment: I did :-) Load the url in new browser and tick 'w' and untick it. It will modify 'd'.

Comment: You are trying some wierd things man. You will have to write some conditional logic. But I have shown you the way how you can do it. Now its time for me to sleep :)

Comment: oki doki, thank you for your help. This one works fine jsfiddle.net/radek/KDVUG only in ff though. Good night :-)

Comment: @Radek - I thought you had accepted this answer, anyways have a good day.

Comment: I did accepted your answer when you said that it worked and tested it. I accept working solution or an answer that leads me to a working solution. @Cory's answer is working ok but only for ff. I'd prefer yours but it needs more tweaking. I have to finish it or go for the other solution.

Comment: @Radek - Take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ggWJu/16/, I think this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

This works with your example ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7XuUw/)):

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
         $('select option[value$=d]').hide(); 
    } else {
         $('select option[value$=d]').show();  
    }
});
```

The selector `option[value$=d]` finds `option`s with values that end with "d".

Additionally, I would give your `select` and `input` elements some unique IDs so you can pinpoint them as the elements you want to control with jQuery -- this may affect other elements on your page as it is.

Comment: Ehm. I'm pretty sure not every browser supports hiding of `select` list elements.

Comment: @floatless: That's probably true. Poster may have to add/remove the items instead of toggling their visibility.

Comment: Works in firefox. Doesn't in chrome & safari.

Comment: How can I add/remove options? Not sure how I can put the options back.

Comment: Looks like the easiest solution to implement. Pity it works only in ff http://jsfiddle.net/radek/KDVUG/

Answer (score 2):

Is [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/8dMZa/) what you're looking for? See [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event and [contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector documentation.

Comment: Works in firefox. Doesn't in chrome & safari.

Comment: I've [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/8dMZa/8/) fiddle. Now it looks a little bit (or not a little :) uglier, but works in FF, Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Looks good. Does your code remember the index of removed option? What if the options are not sorted before?

Comment: No, it doesn't remember index of the removed element... But using [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method we can store elements into hash (instead of array in my example). Key of hash is the index of option element and the value is option DOM-element.

Answer (score 2):

What you need, is an array in your js part. then from that array, you can build a select element on the fly by itterate the array, and you can manipulate it too on the fly.